# python multiprocessing PID change in sub-process

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import os
def run_proc(name):
    print('Run child process %s (%s)...' % (name, os.getpid()))
    counter = 0
    for i in range(0, 1):
        print("!!!weird process id: %s" % (os.getppid()))
def start():
    p = None
    for i in range(0, 1):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=run_proc, args=('test',))
        p.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Parent process %s.' % os.getpid())
    start()
```

And the running result is :
Parent process 31476.

Run child process test (31488)...

### !!!weird process id: 31476

And my question is : why does the pid number change in a for-loop?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from your code, you are calling [os.getppid()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getppid)
, which returns parent's process ID. Also You can notice, that your "weird" process id is the same as the parent's process id.